# Having issues installing and accessing Directus on Debian based VPS

Tags: directus

I've attempted to install Directus through Sofaculous installer on my VPS and using the instructions laid out here: https://docs.directus.io/installation/git.html and nothing is working. It just gives me a 503 Service Unavailable once its installed.

Setup:
Debian Based VPS on A2hosting.com
Methods of install include Softaculous and attempted to install using git clone.
Folders have the correct permissions

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.